# Locating a quote in Dostoevsky's The Idiot

Tags: identification-request, quote-source, russian-language, fyodor-dostoyevsky

I am trying to locate this quote that I came across. I believe it was spoken by Aglaya (or Nastasya?) in The Idiot, but I'm having trouble locating it:

> “I want to talk about everything with at least one person as I talk about things with myself.”

― Fyodor Dostoyevsky, The Idiot

https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/8980050-i-want-to-talk-about-everything-with-at-least-one

It doesn't have to be exact (maybe different translations treat this quote differently), but which Part/Chapter/Page in the Idiot is this quote located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is from Chapter VIII. A copy of *The Idiot* is freely available from the Internet Archive, and the quote (by Aglaya) appears [here](https://archive.org/details/the-idiot_202104/page/631/mode/2up) on page 632:

> I shall tell you everything, EVERYTHING, even the most important
> things of all, whenever I like, and you are to hide nothing from me on
> your side. I want to speak to at least one person, as I would to
> myself.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for -- thank you! In my P&V Copy, it is on page 429 in Part 3, Chapter 8 and it says "I want to talk about everything with at least one person as I would with myself." It is spoken by Aglaya to the prince.